# how to calculate time complexity for the given code?

Tags: java, algorithm

i m working on a project. i designed an algorithm which has many steps. each step has for loops, for loops inside a for loop. but the biggest one is below code, which has many for loops inside for loop. i am guessing for all the steps in algorithm, the step with highest time complexity is the complexity of the algorithm. but i dont know how to calculate time complexity of algorithm. can you please tell me how to calculate time complexity. code is below.

```
for (z = 0; z <con1; z++) {

    outer:
    for (m = 0; m < con2; m++) {
        if () {

            for (i = 0; i < con3; i++) {         
                if () {

                    for (k = 0; k < con4; k++) {

                        for (j = 0; j < con5; j++) {
                            if () {

                                for (l = 0; l < con6; l++) {

                                }

                                for (r = 0; r < con3; r++) {
                                    if () {

                                    }
                                }

                                for (n = 0; n < con6; n++) {

                                }

                                for (s = 0; s < con4; s++) {
                                    if(){   

                                    }
                                }

                                break outer;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125898/tool-for-calculating-cyclomatic-complexity

Comment: Given the sparse code here, could you tell us the probabilities of true/false conditions for each `if` statement?

Comment: each "if" is true at least once before exiting the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sparse information available, the complexity for the worst case is probably along the order of `O(con1 * con2 * con3 * con4 * con5( 2*con6 + con3 + con4))`

Comment: if i put numbers into con1, con2.. like con1=10, con2=260, con3=53, con4=53, con5=260,con6=9 and calculate the time complexity what will be the answer and will it be  nanoseconds?? because if it is calculated it turns into a very big number.

Comment: @user3552285 It doesn't seem you quite get the point of time complexity... It isn't supposed to give you a hard number that will tell you how long it'll take for your algorithm to run. Plugging in numbers is meaningless.

Comment: Exactly - it's an upper bound on the performance of the algorithm. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Comment: @user3552285 In fact, if each of `con_` were constant, your algorithm would technically have O(1) complexity (if memory serves), as the upper bound for your running time would be independent of your input